# Buildroot + QT5 + VC4 opengl - not all examples run ok

Tags: opengl-es, qt5, raspberry-pi3, buildroot

While learning buildroot i write this document 
https://github.com/EliArad/MyDocuments/blob/master/Linux/Buildroot/Buildroot_image_with_Qt5_OPEGN_GLS_2.0_mesa_VC4_driver_in_32_bit.odt

That list the steps i make to get QT5 run with the VC4 driver.

The status for now is that i managed to get the device loaded.
I built image with buildroot with examples for qt5.

But not all the examples are working fine.
some works and the majority not.
for example, the marron game
and animation are not showing ( just gray screen)

many of the help out there are referring to vc4 + raspbian jessie
but i want to make it work using build root.

Can you please tell me what should be done to make it work perfectly 
using buildroot?

Answer (score 1):

*This is not final answer but some issue solved.

I found several things , not yet complete my mission here but                           1. I need the x.org  fbdev , because QT uses this plugin to determine the screen size.                                                                                                     2. Need to install libxkbcommon  for the keyboard                                          3. Need to add  export QT_QPA_EGLFS_NO_LIBINPUT=1     found it here:
4. Need to link between  /usr/share/fonts to /usr/lib/fonts
  because buildroot install it in usr/share/fonts
and qt wants it in usr/lib/fonts ( howto use fontconfig?) 
https://github.com/carlonluca/pot/issues/54
5. QT complains that it cannot decode png files.  there is also some issue with fake kms or kms.  I checked raspbian and there only fake kms works but without mouse left click. if some one use buildroot with QT and can share with us it will be great.

Comment: the problem with the mouse and keyboard was the selection of mesa drivers  evdev , libinput. none of them need to be selected. probably QT uses libinput directly

Comment: I finally get it work , everything is documented here:https://github.com/EliArad/MyDocuments/blob/master/Linux/Buildroot/Buildroot_image_with_Qt5_OPEGN_GLS_2.0_mesa_VC4_driver_in_32_bit.odt

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
You have to select the PNG support on Qt5 package menu

[image]

is better to remove the output/built/qt5-(...) folder to recompile the Qt package

Comment: i found several things , not yet complete my mission here but

Comment: Hi, Thanks , the rebuild helps in this perticular issue. and ofcourse adding the png support